# Lua: How to use input from text box

Tags: lua, roblox

I need to know how to use input from a text box.

e.g. a player types "hi" into the text box and the input appears on a TextLabel.

What variable would that input be stored in?

Answer (score 0):

(textboxname).Text --returns the text that has been inputted